# I am getting an error with my font, and I am not sure why. I have put my font in the same folder, but it is saying the following

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting an error with my font, and I am not sure why. I have put my font in the same folder, the error is the following:

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Coding\Python\Advanced> & "C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "c:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Coding/Python/Advanced/Snake Game/main.py"
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
800 600
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Coding\Python\Advanced\Snake Game\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    myGame = Game()
  File "c:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Coding\Python\Advanced\Snake Game\game.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.font = pygame.font.Font('./Roboto-Regular.ttf',20)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Roboto-Regular.ttf'
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Coding\Python\Advanced>
```

The following is a screenshot of the folder I am using. From what I have searched online, it has something to do with entering the letters dir, then something else, but I am not sure how to do so.

[SCREENSHOT OF FOLDER THAT THE FONT DOCUMENT IS IN (which is the same folder as all other program files)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a77Ai.png)

the directory i am getting when i enter dir is the follwing:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Coding\Python\Advanced


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2022-01-28   6:52 PM                Class 1_Done
d-----        2022-02-09   5:00 PM                Class 2_Done
d-----        2022-02-11   5:35 PM                Class 3_Done
d-----        2022-02-18   6:12 PM                Class 4_Done
d-----        2022-03-02   5:27 PM                Class 5_Done
d-----        2022-03-04   6:36 PM                Class 6_Done
d-----        2022-03-10   1:00 AM                Snake Game
d-----        2022-03-04   6:12 PM                zExamples
d-----        2022-02-02   5:46 PM                zFonts_Roboto
-a----        2022-03-02   5:57 PM            449 START FOR ALL CHALLENGES.py


PS C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Coding\Python\Advanced>
```

I want the directory to go to the "Snake Game" folder

Comment: `I have put my font in the same folder` The code is looking in the _current directory_, which is not the same as the directory where the python code is located.

Comment: how do i change this? i am not sure what a directory is 

Comment: hello? pls explain how to change directory @JohnGordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to put the files in the same directory or sub directory. You also need to set the working directory.
The resource (image, font, sound, etc.) file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python script.
The name and path of the file can be retrieved with [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working can be changed with [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).
Put the following at the beginning of your code to set the working directory to the same as the script's directory:

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```